# Let $f\colon A\rightarrow B$. Then $f$ is surjective iff for every pair of functions $g,h\colon B\rightarrow C$, $g\circ f=h\circ f$ implies $g=h$.

Tags: functions

Let $f\colon A\rightarrow B$. Then $f$ is surjective iff for every pair of functions $g,h\colon B\rightarrow C$, $g\circ f=h\circ f$ implies  $g=h$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume f is surjective. Then for all b in B we have an $a_b$ such that $f(a_b) = b$. So then if $g\circ f = h\circ f$, then for any b in B we can show g(b) = h(b), by simply taking $g(b) = g\circ f(a_b) = h\circ f(a_b) = h(b)$.

Now assume the right side. And for a contradiction assume f is not surjective. Then there exists a b such that for all a in a $f(a) \neq b$. But then $g\circ f = h\circ f$ doesn't imply $h(b) = g(b)$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: The first paragraph looks good!  But the last sentence doesn't quite make sense to me.

Comment: Do you mean "But then $g\circ f = h\circ f$ doesn't imply $h(b) = g(b)$, which is a contradiction." this part?

Comment: Right.  What are $g$ and $h$ in this paragraph?

Comment: So we assumed for any two functions g, h the right side is true. Define b as earlier, then you can construct functions g,h such that $g(x) = h(x)$ for all x in B\{b} and $g(b) \neq h(b)$. Then $gf = hf$, but $g \neq h$.

Comment: Yes, that looks much better!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

Suppose $f$ is surjective. let $g,h: B\rightarrow C$ be such that $g\circ f=h\circ f$. Let $b\in B$. Then $\exists a\in A$ such that $f(a) =b$ because $f$ is surjective. Now, $g(b) = g(f(a)) = h(f(a)) = h(b)$. This is true for every $b\in B$. So $g=h$.

Conversely suppose that for every pair of functions $g,h: B\rightarrow C$, $g\circ f = h\circ f$ implies $g=f$. Suppose, on the contrary that $f$ is not surjective. Then $\exists b_0\in B$ such that $f(a) \neq b_0$ for all $a\in A$. Now, construct two functions $g, h: B\rightarrow C$ such that $g(x) = h(x)$ if $x\in B$, $x\neq b_0$ and $g(b_0)\neq h(b_o)$. Then, $g\circ f(x) = g(f(x)) =h(f(x)) , x\in A$. Note that $f(x) \neq b_0$ for all $x\in A$. Clearly, $g\circ f = h\circ f$ but $g\neq h$ because $g(b_0) \neq h(b_0)$. This contradicts our hypothesis. So, $f$ must be surjective.

Comment: You may want to add something about $C$ to ensure that such functions $g,h$ can be constructed.

Comment: @ Andrés E. Caicedo: Do you mean in one case we consider C be a singleton set in which case the implication is obvious. And  if C has more than one element, then it will validate the construction of the two functions $g$ and $h$ as described in the proof. Please make this point clear.